# Is there a recommended maximum size for an input array in a Solidity smart contract?

Tags: solidity, security, arrays

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "./interfaces/IERC20.sol";

contract Airdrop {
    function airdropToken(
        address _token,
        address[] calldata _receivers,
        uint256[] calldata _amounts
    ) external {
        require(_receivers.length == _amounts.length, "_receivers.length not the same as _amounts.length");        
        for (uint256 i; i < _receivers.length; i++) {
            require(IERC20(_token).transferFrom(tx.origin, _receivers[i], _amounts[i]), "Token send failed");
        }
    }
}
```

I have this Airdrop contract code and I would like to know if it's considered best practice to limit the size of the input array to avoid really long transactions, and/or gas errors. How important would it be to add the following *require* statement for checking the array input sizes?

```
require(_receivers.length <= 200, "Too many transfers");
```

Comment: Usually the block gas limit works as the limiting factor for on-chain transactions. I won't hardcode an explicit limit, unless there's a valid reason (for example you need at most 199 investors).

Answer (score 0):

There are no limits in specification, arrays may go up to 2^256-1 elements. But the maximum allocation size for dynamic memory arrays is 2^64-1

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer but I don't think it's quite the answer I need.  I can't push 2^256-1 elements in a single transaction, so I'd like to know if there's a "best-practice" allowing a maximum number of items in an input array for a single transaction. Is 2^64-1 the number for it?

Comment: Sorry for that, best practice samples while using a dyamic arary is given here check these, i think it will help you: https://blog.soliditylang.org/2020/04/06/memory-creation-overflow-bug/